# Power automate Http request body as RemoteExecutionObject, How to retreive particualr field from Input argument

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, power-automate

I have Power automate which run as webhook to dynamics i.e Trigger is HTTP request.

Once this request run it contains body as RemoteExecutionObject.

Example below

```
{
  "BusinessUnitId": "eedd1dcd-1318-e611-80d3-005056936c69",
  "CorrelationId": "8385868f-4fa4-42a0-9c83-6b63a5cd4774",
  "Depth": 2,
  "InitiatingUserAzureActiveDirectoryObjectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "InitiatingUserId": "91ff1dcd-1318-e611-80d3-005056936c69",
  "InputParameters": [
    {
      "key": "Target",
      "value": {
        "__type": "Entity:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
        "Attributes": [
          {
            "key": "crm_abc",
            "value": null
          },
......
......
}
```

I wish to retrieve particualr field and it's value from InputParameetrs in Power automate.

[Here is one close to example mentioning how it can be achieved. But it is still not clear](https://crmtipoftheday.com/1362/trigger-power-automate-on-associate-disassociate/)

Does any one have idea about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this particular challenge with variables and using array/object one at a time.

for ex: First retrieved InputParameters as array from Json

```
triggerBody()['InputParameters']
```

then used index 0 so that I get complete InputParameters  as object

```
 triggerBody()['InputParameters'][0]
```

Then to get Values Array as below

```
triggerBody()['InputParameters'][0]['value']['Attributes']
```

and then attributes as Array

```
triggerBody()['InputParameters'][0]['value']['Attributes']
```

Note we can directly retrive Attributes with above expression.

Now to get particular field from Attributes array, I used filter array action from power automate and used it as

Similar way we can retrive various fields

[image]